# How to create a listbox with all firewall rules and enable editing?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm a beginner and working with Windows Forms.

My task it to fill up a Listbox with a list of all of the local firewall rules, and then if possible add a button where you can select one of them and edit/delete them and another button to create new ones.

For now I'm mostly worried about just populating the listbox, so please focus on that if you could.

The simpler the solution the better, and if there are any references I need to add to the program in order for yours to work, please remember to mention them.

--EDIT--

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "PowerShell_ISE.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "Get-NetFirewallRule -PolicyStore ActiveStore";
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            process.Start();
            string q = "";
            while (!process.HasExited)
            {
                q += process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            }

            listboxfirewall.Items.Clear();

                listboxfirewall.Items.Add(q);
        }
```

So this is part of the code I have. The button here used is supposed to fill up the table with the output of the powershell command specified, which should give all the rules. Although, I can and may probably be wrong about the command itself too. So with what should I replace this code in order to fill up the table?

Comment: We work on specific coding problems here.  You didn't post one.

Comment: Where should I ask this then, or how can I make it a valid question?

Comment: [Is there any .NET API to get all the firewall rules](//stackoverflow.com/q/10342260)

Comment: For more info on asking a good question go to the [help] and read [ask]. Your question leaves a lot of unanswered questions. Have you created a form? A listbox? Can you populate the listbox with anything? Where _exactly_ are you having a problem?

Comment: I don't quite get the doubt, but imagine you're trying to build what I mentioned from scratch. You have a form with an empty listbox in it and a few (three in this case) buttons on the side with no action attributed to them so far. That's the scenario I was implying. How can you "fetch" all the local firewall rules, fill the listbox with them, then make the buttons interact with that list? @JohnnyMopp

Comment: `make the buttons interact with that list?`  How should we know how you plan to interact with those items in the list?  The issue with the post is it doesn't focus on a single issue.  Do that, and show the code that isn't working.

Comment: I specified the interactions I intended to happen on the original post, and my single issue here, if you will (or most important one) is how to fill up an empty listbox with a list of all the local firewall rules. I can't show the code that isn't working because I have none, I'm starting from scratch and don't know how to do this which is my first step to do. @LarsTech

Comment: Having buttons that add-edit-delete items from a list is a different issue than listing all the firewall rules.  You need to start with a tutorial on how to subscribe to the click events and how to add and remove items from a list.  Once you have that figured out, then look at your firewall issue.

Comment: But my first issue here is what you just said, listing all the firewall rules. That's what my main goal is right now. Any idea how I can do only that, forgetting about the buttons for a second here? @LarsTech

Comment: No.  If you don't know how to make button events and make changes to a generic list, that is step one.  You don't design a sports car and then figure out how an engine works.

Comment: I have a main form. I have a button on that main form. When I click it, it opens a new form, where the listbox is. I just want the listbox to display the firewall rules, that's all. @LarsTech

Comment: Did you read the link that @JohnnyMopp provided?

Comment: Yes I did, I had seen that post before I posted my question. It gives me a bunch of errors and doesn't work properly at all, besides I couldn't really understand what was being done. That's why I also specified that I am a beginner and that if possible, include all the references that need to be made and extra stuff you have to do to make the code work. @LarsTech

Comment: I'll type up answer that should get you started....

Comment: That was your mistake here then.  You should have posted the code you tried to use (referencing the link in your question so we know where the original code came from) and telling us what errors you were getting.  Which lines of code were causing those errors.

Comment: My bad then, I just assumed that it would be no help to just copy and paste code and ask why it didn't work. I can edit the post and add that then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first have to add a reference to "firewallapi.dll" (it should be in %WINDIR%\system32). Use the "Project->Add Reference" menu then select "Browse..." and browse to that file.

Then, add `using NetFwTypeLib;` to your source file.

An example of populating the listbox:

```
private void getRulesBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Type typeFWPolicy2 = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2");
    INetFwPolicy2 fwPolicy2 = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(typeFWPolicy2);

    foreach (INetFwRule rule in fwPolicy2.Rules)
    {
        int index = listBox1.Items.Add(rule.Name);
    }
}
```

You can also use a listview. This example assumes you have a listview with 3 columns:

```
private void getRulesBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Type typeFWPolicy2 = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2");
    INetFwPolicy2 fwPolicy2 = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(typeFWPolicy2);

    foreach (INetFwRule rule in fwPolicy2.Rules)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(rule.Name, 0);
        // There are other members, just using these as an example
        item.SubItems.Add(rule.RemoteAddresses);
        item.SubItems.Add(rule.Description);
        item.Tag = rule;    // Save for later retrieval
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's perfect, a great start point. Do you have any idea if I can add details to the list, as in, different columns where I can show if the rule is active or not, the group it's in, etc? Either way, thank you for this little bit already

Comment: Use a [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of a listbox to show multiple columns.

Comment: Code you wrote above works the same way in a ListView?

Comment: @S.Maia Sure.  Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! @Johnny Mopp